# Ajax + Google Contacts API issue viewing group membership

Tags: ajax, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to figure out some code I got at one point that uses Ajax to get contacts from my feed, but I'm not sure how to access the group membership of said contacts to display that info elsewhere.

Here's a little snippet of my code:

```
//user is a specific contact
//options is an array var
//names is an array var
//phones is an array var
//groups is an array var

if (user.gd$email == null) options.push("");
else options.push(user.gd$email[0].address);

if (user.title.$t == null || user.title.$t == "" ) names.push(options[i]);
else names.push(user.title.$t);

if (user.gd$phoneNumber == null) phones.push("0");
else phones.push(user.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t);

//this is the code I added based on the 3 existing if-elses above
if (user.gd$groupMembershipInfo == null) groups.push("");
else groups.push(user.gd$groupMembershipInfo[0].$t);
```

Comment: Do you have a backend where you can store data and fetch them later so you can display the data in other places?

Comment: Using [Contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) or [People](https://developers.google.com/people/) api?

Comment: I don't have a backend, no. I'm scripting it together within an HTML page using array variables. Will I need to expand to storing the array values in separate files for later recall?

Comment: I'm using the Contacts API